# What is the proper way to code a button click into an event statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm trying to code a small function that returns a statement if a double click event occurs but I don't know the proper syntax here and info on this was a bit scarce and I can see that something is clearly missing just by intuition probably another param. after `double-button-1` can someone help/school me real quick THANKS! Heres what I got:

http://pastebin.com/VdQ39q2A (here is the full code)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 114, in _cnfmerge
for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()



self.label1 = Label(c, text="Blue Buff", fg="Blue",font=("",30))

def reset_timer(self):
   if self.label1.event.type == ("<Double-Button-1>"):
     return self.label1.configure(text="Blue Buff")

def label_clicked_two(self,event):
    self.label1.configure(self.reset_timer)
    self.label1.update()

self.label1.bind("<Double-Button-1>",self.label_clicked_two)
```

Comment: 1) You are missing a colon (:) at the end of the if statement

Comment: What graphic ui library are you using?

Comment: It is Tkinter. I saw code in some previous question.

Comment: It is indeed Tkinter @furas thanks !

Comment: 1) I don't see colon in new code, 2) after `if` you need indention. 3) print `self.label1.event.type` to see how it looks like.

Comment: Show full error message. What is `self.label1` ? Why do you use `event.type` on it ? How do you bind event to widget ?

Answer (score 0):

I made some example with event but we still don't know what is the problem in your code.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def test(event):
    print 'event:', event
    print 'type:', event.type # 4

master = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(master, text="QUIT", command=master.destroy, width=20, heigh=5)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(master, text="OK", width=20, heigh=5)
b2.pack()

b2.bind('<Double-Button-1>', test)

master.mainloop()
```

.

```
event: <Tkinter.Event instance at 0x1c79128>
type: 4
```

Comment: If it would be best i mean i could just paste in the whole program?

Comment: If program is in one file then use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and paste link.

Comment: i posted the link up top in the opening.